# How to create rows based on the range of all values between min and max in Snowflake (SQL)?

Tags: sql, range, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Assume I have the following data:

| ID | T_Min | T_Max |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 5 |
| 2 | 1 | 4 |

I would like to create the following table using SQL (Snowflake):

| ID | T |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |

Does someone know how to do this? Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample data:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE T1 (
    ID INT,
    T_Min INT,
    T_Max INT);

INSERT INTO T1(ID, T_Min, T_Max)
SELECT * FROM VALUES (1, 3, 5), (2, 1, 4) t(ID, T_Min, T_Max);
```

Solution:

```
WITH N AS (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY SEQ4()) AS T FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT => 1000)) -- Set to the maximum value of the difference between T_Max and T_Min
)
SELECT T1.ID, N.T
  FROM T1
  JOIN N ON N.T BETWEEN T1.T_Min AND T1.T_Max
 ORDER BY T1.ID, N.T;
```

Comment: This will have gaps in the range,  replace the `SEQ4()+1` with `ROW_NUMBER over ( ORDER BY SEQ4()) to void having gaps

Comment: I don't think this happens here, but you are right @SimeonPilgrim: _"When operating on a large quantity of data, gaps can appear in a sequence."_ I changed to ROW_NUMBER. Thank you for your attention.