# Creating rows in a table based on min and max date in Snowflake SQL

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there a relatively simple way to create rows in a table based on a range of dates?

For example; given:

| ID | Date_min | Date_max |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-02-01 | 2022-20-05 |
| 2 | 2022-02-09 | 2022-02-12 |

I want to output:

| ID | Date_in_Range |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-02-01 |
| 1 | 2022-02-02 |
| 1 | 2022-02-03 |
| 1 | 2022-02-04 |
| 1 | 2022-02-05 |
| 2 | 2022-02-09 |
| 2 | 2022-02-10 |
| 2 | 2022-02-11 |
| 2 | 2022-02-12 |

I saw a solution when the range is integer based ([How to create rows based on the range of all values between min and max in Snowflake (SQL)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69724049/how-to-create-rows-based-on-the-range-of-all-values-between-min-and-max-in-snowf/69724268#69724268?))

But in order to use that approach GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT => 1000) I have to convert my dates to integers and back, and it just gets very messy very quick, especially since I need to apply this to millions of rows.

So, I was wondering if there is a simpler way to do it when dealing with dates instead of integers? Any hints anyone can provide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another one without using `generator` -

```
with data (ID,Date_min,Date_max) as (
select * from values
(1,to_date('2022-02-01','YYYY-DD-MM'),to_date('2022-20-05','YYYY-DD-MM')),
(2,to_date('2022-02-09','YYYY-DD-MM'),to_date('2022-02-12','YYYY-DD-MM'))
)
select id,
Date_min,
Date_max,
dateadd(day, index, Date_min) day_slots from data,
table(split_to_table(repeat(',',datediff(day, Date_min, Date_max)-1),','));
```

SQL with first date -

```
with data (ID,Date_min,Date_max) as (
select * from values
(1,to_date('2022-02-01','YYYY-DD-MM'),to_date('2022-20-05','YYYY-DD-MM')),
(2,to_date('2022-02-09','YYYY-DD-MM'),to_date('2022-02-12','YYYY-DD-MM'))
)
select id,
dateadd(month, index-1, Date_min) day_slots from data,
table(split_to_table(repeat(',',datediff(month, Date_min, Date_max)),','));
```

Comment: Can be customized to add date or months accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, Pankaj. I had to make a small tweak to your code as it was missing the first date, but the approach absolutely works.

Comment: Added the tweaked code to answer.

Answer (score 0):

> But in order to use that approach GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT => 1000) I have to convert my dates to integers and back, and it just gets very messy very quick, especially since I need to apply this to millions of rows.

There is no need to convert date to int back and forth, just simple [DATEADD('day', num, start_date)](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/dateadd.html)

Pseudocode:

```
WITH sample_data(id, date_min, date_max) AS (
   SELECT 1, '2022-02-01'::DATE, '2022-02-05'::DATE 
   UNION 
   SELECT 2, '2022-02-09'::DATE, '2022-02-12'::DATE
) , numbers AS (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY SEQ4())-1 AS num -- 0 based
  FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT => 1000)) -- should match max anticipated span
)
SELECT s.id, DATEADD(DAY, n.num, s.date_min) AS calculated_date
FROM sample_data AS s
JOIN numbers AS n
 ON DATEADD('DAY', n.num, s.date_min) BETWEEN s.date_min AND s.date_max
ORDER BY s.id, calculated_date;
```

Ouptut:

[image]